# How do I migrate from R66 to R67 given that computeCentroids () has been removed?

Tags: three.js, migration

I have upgrade three.js from r66 to latest version r69.
But by removing the `computeCentroids()` from the code, my objects are not placed and rendered correctly (see http://jsfiddle.net/j8DN6/8/).

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by finding the midpoint of the hypotenuse.

http://www.coedu.usf.edu/main/departments/sped/PROPEL/documents/MicrosoftWord-Midpoint.pdf (See Section 2)